# PowerBI - multiple data type in single column power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I have data in below format for `Jan` to `Dec`. I want show `Gross margin` in % format and rest of the category in whole number. It is not possible to convert only a part of set of numbers in % format in power BI in single column. If I try to change the format it changes the whole column.

| Date | Category | Actual | Budget | Plan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | Revenue | 12 | 34 | 67 |
| February | Revenue | 34 | 22 | 34 |
| March | Revenue | 22 | 11 | 44 |
| January | Cost | 3 | 45 | 21 |
| February | Cost | 22 | 4 | 3 |
| March | Cost | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| January | Gross Profit | 9 | -11 | 46 |
| February | Gross Profit | 12 | 18 | 31 |
| March | Gross Profit | 18 | 7 | 40 |
| January | Gross Margin | 75% | -32% | 69% |
| February | Gross Margin | 35% | 82% | 91 |
| March | Gross Margin | 82% | 64% | 91% |

Comment: It is not possible to mix different formats in one column. The only way you can achieve that is to make it a text column, and format the data yourself in DAX (e.g. using [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax) function) or M (e.g. using [Number.ToText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-totext)). But keep in mind that the column will be text and Power BI will not be able to aggregate amounts from it.

Comment: You could turn everything into normal numbers and then make measures based on category. Or, if you have many categories, make an extra column that specifies if it is a number or percentage and base your measures on that.